# Apply thousand separator given the IFormatProvider just like decimal one

Tags: c#, .net

The code below works fine for decimal separator, which means, for pt-pt it renders "," and en-us it does "."

How can I accomplish the same behavior with the thousand separator?

```
        decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(20000.01);

        IFormatProvider portuguese = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-pt");
        IFormatProvider english = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us");

        Console.WriteLine(dec.ToString(portuguese));
        Console.WriteLine(dec.ToString(english));
```

Comment: You can create decimal values via `M` suffix: `decimal dec = 20000.01M`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a format string that includes a thousands separator.

E.g. a [standard format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx):

```
dec.ToString("N2", portuguese);
```

or a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx):

```
dec.ToString("#,###.00", portuguese);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is admittedly a shot in the dark.

```
decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(20000.01);

IFormatProvider portuguese = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-pt");
IFormatProvider english = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us");

Console.WriteLine(dec.ToString({0:C},portuguese)); //tell it that its currency
Console.WriteLine(dec.ToString(({0:C},english));   //tell it that its currency
```